# GeoMesa Native API (Accumulo) - Polygon intersection filter: missing "the_geom" in SimpleFeature

Tags: java, accumulo, geomesa

I am ingesting data from a shapefile (the TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp) into geomesa (on accumulo) via the native api. I then want to, again using the Native Api, query the data for anything in geomesa that contains a point (lat,lon), given by the user (basically any polygon in geomesa that contains the point).

More-or-less mimicking the "Q. What did I click on?: Use a point for to Check Polygon Layers" from http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/main/filter.html

```
GeoMesaQuery q = GeoMesaQuery.GeoMesaQueryBuilder.builder()
.within(-180.0,-90.0,180.0,90.0)   // needed or the query throws a null-pointer ex
.filter(ff.contains(ff.property("the_geom"), ff.literal(point)))
.build();
```

however, when I run the query I get an error (in accumulo):

```
Failed to get multiscan result
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't handle property 'the_geom' for feature type  dtg:Date,payload:Bytes,*geom:Geometry:srid=4326:index-value=true,FIPS:String,ISO2:String,ISO3:String
    at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.scan.ScanTask.get(ScanTask.java:126)
    at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.TabletServer$ThriftClientHandler.continueMultiScan(TabletServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.TabletServer$ThriftClientHandler.startMultiScan(TabletServer.java:665)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.trace.wrappers.RpcServerInvocationHandler.invoke(RpcServerInvocationHandler.java:46)
    at org.apache.accumulo.server.rpc.RpcWrapper$1.invoke(RpcWrapper.java:74)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.startMultiScan(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.tabletserver.thrift.TabletClientService$Processor$startMultiScan.getResult(TabletClientService.java:2381)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.tabletserver.thrift.TabletClientService$Processor$startMultiScan.getResult(TabletClientService.java:2365)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
    at org.apache.accumulo.server.rpc.TimedProcessor.process(TimedProcessor.java:63)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.AbstractNonblockingServer$FrameBuffer.invoke(AbstractNonblockingServer.java:518)
    at org.apache.accumulo.server.rpc.CustomNonBlockingServer$CustomFrameBuffer.invoke(CustomNonBlockingServer.java:106)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.Invocation.run(Invocation.java:18)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.accumulo.fate.util.LoggingRunnable.run(LoggingRunnable.java:35)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't handle property 'the_geom' for feature type  dtg:Date,payload:Bytes,*geom:Geometry:srid=4326:index-value=true,FIPS:String,ISO2:String,ISO3:String
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.filter.expression.FastPropertyName.evaluate(FastPropertyName.scala:61)
    at org.geotools.filter.GeometryFilterImpl.getGeometries(GeometryFilterImpl.java:108)
    at org.geotools.filter.GeometryFilterImpl.evaluate(GeometryFilterImpl.java:237)
    at org.geotools.filter.AndImpl.evaluate(AndImpl.java:44)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.iterators.KryoLazyFilterTransformIterator$$anonfun$init$5.apply(KryoLazyFilterTransformIterator.scala:78)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.iterators.KryoLazyFilterTransformIterator$$anonfun$init$5.apply(KryoLazyFilterTransformIterator.scala:78)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.iterators.KryoLazyFilterTransformIterator.findTop(KryoLazyFilterTransformIterator.scala:117)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.iterators.KryoLazyFilterTransformIterator.seek(KryoLazyFilterTransformIterator.scala:94)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.iterators.system.SourceSwitchingIterator.readNext(SourceSwitchingIterator.java:135)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.iterators.system.SourceSwitchingIterator.seek(SourceSwitchingIterator.java:182)
    at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.tablet.Tablet.lookup(Tablet.java:562)
    at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.tablet.Tablet.lookup(Tablet.java:681)
    at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.scan.LookupTask.run(LookupTask.java:114)
    at org.apache.htrace.wrappers.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:57)
```

I can see that my feature has a *geom type, but NOT a "the_geom" type. I then tried to overwrite the SimpleFeatureView 'populate' and 'getExtraAttributes' methods, but getExtraAttributes won't let me bind a geometry... (note: I also tried to give the setAttribute the gmtr from the populate signature with the same error).

```
GeoMesaIndex<Shapefile> index = AccumuloGeoMesaIndex.build(
                                                 config.getString("tableName"),
                                                 config.getString("zookeeperHostPort"),
                                                 config.getString("accumuloInstance"),
                                                 config.getString("user"),
                                                 config.getString("password"),
                                                 false,
                                                 new ShapefileValueSerializer(),
                                                 new SimpleFeatureView<Shapefile>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void populate(SimpleFeature sf, Shapefile t, String string, byte[] bytes, Geometry gmtr, Date date) {
                                                        sf.setAttribute("the_geom", t.the_geom);
                                                 }

                                                    @Override
                                                    public List<AttributeDescriptor> getExtraAttributes() {
                                                        AttributeTypeBuilder atb = new AttributeTypeBuilder();
                                                        return Lists.newArrayList(
                                                            atb.binding(Geometry.class).buildDescriptor("the_geom")
                                                                                                                        );
                                                    }
                                                });
```

with error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid spec string at index 85. Expected one of: attribute type binding, geometry type binding.
at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.geotools.SimpleFeatureTypes$.createType(SimpleFeatureTypes.scala:98)
at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.geotools.SimpleFeatureTypes$.createType(SimpleFeatureTypes.scala:85)
at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.geotools.InitBuilder.build(SftBuilder.scala:174)
at org.locationtech.geomesa.api.BaseBigTableIndex$.org$locationtech$geomesa$api$BaseBigTableIndex$$buildSimpleFeatureType(BaseBigTableIndex.scala:132)
at org.locationtech.geomesa.api.BaseBigTableIndex.<init>(BaseBigTableIndex.scala:40)
at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.nativeapi.AccumuloGeoMesaIndex.<init>(AccumuloGeoMesaIndex.scala:26)
at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.nativeapi.AccumuloGeoMesaIndex$.buildWithView(AccumuloGeoMesaIndex.scala:72)
at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.nativeapi.AccumuloGeoMesaIndex$.build(AccumuloGeoMesaIndex.scala:53)
at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.nativeapi.AccumuloGeoMesaIndex.build(AccumuloGeoMesaIndex.scala)
at com.comcept.geomesa.ingesttool.AccumuloGeomesaNGAIngest.main(AccumuloGeomesaNGAIngest.java:148)
Caused by: org.parboiled.errors.ParsingException: Invalid spec string at index 85. Expected one of: attribute type binding, geometry type binding.
at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.geotools.SimpleFeatureSpecParser$$anonfun$parse$1.apply(SimpleFeatureSpecParser.scala:39)
at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.geotools.SimpleFeatureSpecParser$$anonfun$parse$1.apply(SimpleFeatureSpecParser.scala:39)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.geotools.SimpleFeatureSpecParser$.parse(SimpleFeatureSpecParser.scala:39)
at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.geotools.SimpleFeatureSpecParser$.parse(SimpleFeatureSpecParser.scala:28)
... 10 more
```

So with all that said, is it possible to do a polygon point containment check using a filter using GeoMesa's Native Api? I have not been able to query the geometry using ff.property(any version of "geom", e.g., "the_geom", "*geom", etc)

Comment: How did you ingest the data from the shapefile? In the insert method of the native API, if you pass the geometry from the_geom, then you will be able to query it by the name 'geom'.
https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/master/geomesa-native-api/src/main/java/org/locationtech/geomesa/api/GeoMesaIndex.java#L51

Comment: Emilio you are the man, I was inserting via gf.createPoint (like I saw in a tutorial and in the tests in geomesa's github page.).  Should I take this question down or just leave it up to help other people who might be inserting wrong?

Comment: Nice, glad to help. Yeah, I'd leave it up for posterity. If there's anything in the docs/tutorials that could be clearer let us know - you can chat in our gitter or send an email to the users list (links on geomesa.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding as an official answer:
It is possible to do a polygon point containment check with the GeoMesa native API - you just have to ensure that you use the geometry you wish to query when you call `insert` [here](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/geomesa_2.11-1.3.2/geomesa-native-api/src/main/java/org/locationtech/geomesa/api/GeoMesaIndex.java#L51). Then the geometry is available for querying under the name `"geom"`.